# how to validate fields in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I need to make a validation in datatables array.

```
if typeoftransfer === '2' then return 'LL' 
elseif typeoftransfer === '3' return 'SA'
```

I have been reading datatables documentation and didn'f found how  to do it.
Here is my array code on the server processing:

```
$columns = array(
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`res_code`',      'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'res_code' ),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`transfer_id`',       'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'transfer_id' ),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`typeoftransfer`',    'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'typeoftransfer'),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`clavedest`',         'dt' => 3, 'field' => 'clavedest' ),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`arrivalhotel`',  'dt' => 4, 'field' => 'arrivalhotel' ),
  array( 'db' => '`clien`.`fullname`',      'dt' => 5, 'field' => 'fullname' ),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`peoplearrival`',     'dt' => 6, 'field' => 'peoplearrival' ),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`res_status`',        'dt' => 7, 'field' => 'res_status' ),
  array( 'db' => '`reser`.`typeoftransfer`',    'dt' => 8, 'field' => 'typeoftransfer', 
  data => function function( $d, $row ) {
            if ( typeoftransfer === '2' ) {
                return "LL";
              }else{
                return "SA";    
            }
        }
    ),
);
```

Any idea ?, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, this worls for me

```
 'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
          if($d == '2'){
              return 'LL';
          }elseif($d == '3'){
              return 'SA';
        }
```

Regards,